# 03 honda civic will not start

Tags: honda, starting, civic

03 honda civic will not start. Ran fine night before next day would not start. All lights and gauges came on with out problem but would not start, no clicking, nothing . Tried to jump start and nothing, checked fuses an all good as far as I can tell. Replaced ignition switch an still nothing.  Any ideas? Please help!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Since you seem to suggest that it's not a battery problem, if you're not hearing anything happening when you turn the key, it is likely to be your starter motor solenoid or the relay. You'll need a multimeter to check voltage across either.

Comment: Or, the ignition key switch. In other words, something in the electrical starter circuit.

Answer (score 0):

I would check the starter connections as well as the starter itself.  You can take the starter off and take it to AutoZone.  They will check your starter for free or you can Take the starter off and test the solenoid and the actuator yourself at home with jumper cables.

Answer (score -1):

Fuel Injection might be faulty check Air Filter element also.

Comment: Could you expand on this? What might be wrong with the injection? How should you check it, etc?